# Apply datatemplate to custom object?

Tags: c#, wpf

Assuming I have a class derived from Shape. I'm looking for way how to implement support for binding it with datatemplate. 
A datatemplate looking something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>    
  <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Path x:Name="path" Data="F1 M 0.0692474,6.76634C -2.5902,6.76634 -4.91351,8.20551 -6.16436,10.3475L 0.0665311,-10.3179L 6.29167,10.3284C 5.03818,8.19696 2.72079,6.76634 0.0692474,6.76634 Z " />
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It's clear for me how to apply Datatemplate to controls, such as buttons, textboxs, listviews and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TemplatePartAttribute` does what you like.
[See this tutorial](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/writing-reusable-custom-control-in-wpf.html) for info on how to write a Custom Control that supports Templating and see how you can mix your shape in there.